# Symfony - Access form name by reference

Tags: symfony, twig, symfony-forms

I have a form with a number of questions. They are not tied to an entity so are generated dynamically in the form type class

```
class QuestionnaireType extends AbstractType
{
    private $questions = [
        0 => 'Question 1',
        1 => 'Question 2',
        2 => 'Question 3',
    ];

    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        foreach ($this->questions as $key => $val) {
            $builder->add($key, ChoiceType::class, [
                'choices' => [
                    1 => 'Yes',
                    2 => 'No',
                ]
            ]);
        }
    }
}
```

I want to access these form elements in my twig template in a loop. I tried the following but it doesn't work:

```
{% block content %}
    {{ form_start(form) }}
    {{ form_errors(form) }}
    {% for i in 0..2 %}
        {{ form_label(form.i) }}
        {{ form_widget(form.i) }}
    {% endfor %}
    {{ form_end(form) }}
{% endblock %}
```

Is it possible to access form elements by reference from within a twig template?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`form.i` doesn't work because you have no form field named `i`, and when accessing an array or object attributes via `foo.bar`, Twig won't try to interpret `bar` as a variable.

This said, you can also access array keys and objects attributes via the syntax `foo[bar]` where `bar` **will always** be interpreted as a variable, and where `foo['bar']` will then be an equivalent to `foo.bar`.
So in your case, `form[i]`.

So this should work for your case:

```
{% block content %}
    {{ form_start(form) }}
    {{ form_errors(form) }}
    {% for i in 0..2 %}
        {{ form_label(form[i]) }}
        {{ form_widget(form[i]) }}
    {% endfor %}
    {{ form_end(form) }}
{% endblock %}
```

---

Another solution would be to use the [`attribute`](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/3.x/functions/attribute.html) function:

```
{% block content %}
    {{ form_start(form) }}
    {{ form_errors(form) }}
    {% for i in 0..2 %}
        {{ form_label(attribute(form, i)) }}
        {{ form_widget(attribute(form, i)) }}
    {% endfor %}
    {{ form_end(form) }}
{% endblock %}
```